# Using Laravel AdminLTE

Tags: laravel-5.4, adminlte

I developed an application using Laravel adminLTE. I can login that application using `php artisan serve` command. But I can't login without using `php artisan serve` command. Below is the screen shot.

[image]

How can I debug this situation ?

Comment: Well, change your Appurl in config/app.php and eventually also in .env :D

Comment: becuse you need to start server before using it,you can not run 127.0.0.1 means localhost without php artisan serve.